# Adding element in a HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

I have this piece of code, expecting that the size was 2, but is 1

```
Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();


         userRoles.add(new UserRole(user, roleService.findByName(RolesEnum.ADMIN.getRoleName())));
         userRoles.add(new UserRole(user, roleService.findByName(RolesEnum.BASIC.getRoleName())));


         System.out.println("#################");
         System.out.println("userRoles -> " + userRoles.size());
         System.out.println("#################");
```

Comment: Then your `UserRole` probably defines equality based on `user` alone or your `roleService` is returning the same results in the above code. You should read up on how `HashSet` works. Although if you are a senior developer like your profile says, you should know how it works.

Comment: Did you override `hashCode` and `equals` method?

Comment: Check if `user1.equals(user2) == true`, and if `hashCode(user1) == hashCode(user2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a hashset duplicate values are not inserted. Its a built in feature of the Set data structure in java. Since both inserted values are equal in your case the second value won't be inserted. Try inserting different values to the data structure.

Comment: BTW. It's not only a feature of the HashSet, any Set in Java must not allow duplicate values.